# Decomposing binary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, binary, symplectic-linear-algebra

Given a $2n \times 2n$ binary symplectic matrix$^1$ $M$, I need to decompose that into a product of matrices from the following set S. It is guaranteed that multiple such decompositions exist.

$S = \{ A \} \cup \{ B\}$

Where set $A$ contains matrices of the form:

$A = I_{2n \times 2n} + (1)_{n+i,j} + (1)_{n+j,i} + (1)_{n+i,i} + (1)_{n+j,j}  $

And set $B$ contains matrices of the form:

$B = I_{2n \times 2n} + (1)_{i,n+j} + (1)_{j,n+i} + (1)_{i,n+i} + (1)_{j,n+j}$

$i,j \in [1,n]$

Here $I$ is identity and $(1)_{n+i,j}$ means (n+i,j) element is 1. (If there is better notation to denote this, please let me know.)

If it helps, $M$ also satisfies the following condition:

$^1$ : $M$ is matrix which satisfies $M \cdot J \cdot M^T = J$ where

$J =  \begin{bmatrix}
0_{n \times n} & I_{n \times n}\\
I_{n \times n} & 0_{n \times n} 
\end{bmatrix}$

Any idea on how can I approach this problem? Are there any matrix decomposition, factorization algorithms? If yes, how efficient in terms of computation are they?

Any input would be greatly appricaited!

Comment: I fail to see the difference between matrix of the form $A$ and of the form $B$. Could you provide an example ?

Comment: I have edited it. Result of copy-pasting. My bad.

Comment: are $i$ and $j$ in $[1,n]$ ? if not, what is $(1)_{1, 2n+1}$ ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. My bad.

Comment: basically A an B matrices are of form 

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
I_{n \times n} & 0_{n \times n}\\
Q_{n \times n} & I_{n \times n}
\end{bmatrix}$$ and 

$$B = \begin{bmatrix}
I_{n \times n} & Q_{n \times n}\\
0_{n \times n} & I_{n \times n}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Where $Q$ contains four 1s according to given rules.

Comment: Are you doing quantum computing? The following papers can be helpful: https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.06987, https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.09412